# How to loop through a list with another list that contains a dictionary

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I'm having some trouble with an Ansible Playbook I'm working on. I'm using the [vm_hardware_disk_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/vmware/vmware_rest/vcenter_vm_hardware_disk_module.html) in order to create multiple virtual disks on a specific VM in a specific vCenter.

This is the .yml I have written up that I have in order to loop through the VMs and vCenters.

```yaml
server_list:
- cpu_count: 6
  memory_size: 12288
  name: nodeA
  vcenter: vCenterA
  vdisks:
    - capacity: 107374182400
    - capacity: 214748364800
```

The end goal should be similar to this which goes through the .yml file by index and dynamically changes the CPU/Memory and add a virtual disk if needed:

```yaml
server_list:
- cpu_count: 6
  memory_size: 12288
  name: nodeA
  vcenter: vCenterA
  vdisks:
    - capacity: 107374182400
    - capacity: 214748364800

- cpu_count: 2
  memory_size: 2048
  name: nodeB
  vcenter: vCenterB
  vdisks:
    - capacity: 123415414552
    - capacity: 436345634633
```

As a reference to a recent playbook I created, this is how I loop through the VM and vCenter in order to allow me grab the information I need and upgrade CPU/Memory dynamically.

```yaml
- name: Gather current VM information
  vmware.vmware_rest.vcenter_vm_info:
    vcenter_username: "{{ SECRET.USER }}"
    vcenter_password: "{{ SECRET.PASS }}"
    vcenter_hostname: "{{ item.vcenter }}"
    names: "{{ item.name }}"
  loop: "{{ server_list }}"
  register: vm_info

- name: Upgrade CPU
  vmware.vmware_rest.vcenter_vm_hardware_cpu:
    vcenter_username: "{{ SECRET.USER }}"
    vcenter_password: "{{ SECRET.PASS }}"
    vcenter_hostname: "{{ item.vcenter }}"
    vm: "{{ vm_info.results[item_index]['value'][0]['vm'] }}"
    count: "{{ item.cpu_count }}"
  when: vm_info.results[item_index]['value'][0]['cpu_count'] != item.cpu_count
  loop: "{{ server_list }}"
  loop_control:
    index_var: item_index`
```

This allows me to loop through and dynamically upgrade multiple VMs across different vCenters. This was part one of what I was working on and now I'm trying to implement part 2 which adds the vDisks if specified.

This is the module that creates the virtual disk

```yaml
`- name: Create a new Disk
  vmware.vmware_rest.vcenter_vm_hardware_disk:
   vcenter_username: <username>
   vcenter_password: <password>
   vcenter_hostname: "{{ item.vcenter }}"
   vm: "{{ vm_info.results[item_index]['value'][0]['vm'] }}"
   new_vmdk:
     capacity: "{{ }}" <-- What I need to loop through
     type: SCSI
  loop: "{{ server_list }}"
  loop_control:
     index_var: item_index`
```

I've tried doing multiple options such as

```
item.vdisks | map(attribute='capacity')
item | json_query('[].vdisks[].capacity)
item.vdisks.capacity
```

```yaml
- name: Debug
  ansible.builtin.debug:
   msg: <The Integer Loop I want>
  loop: "{{ server_list }}"
```

This is what what output looks like when I loop the "{{ server_list }}":

```json
{
  "item": {
    "cpu_count": 6,
    "memory_size": 12288,
    "name": "nodeA",
    "vcenter": "vCenterA",
    "vdisks": [
      {
        "capacity": 107374182400
      },
      {
        "capacity": 214748364800
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The end output I would see is it creates the first virtual disk then loops through the task again and creates the second virtual disk. Once that task is complete, it then continues to the next index of the server list which would be another VM and vCenter.

**I need to keep the server_list as the loop as that allows me to loop through the vCenter (Unless another way is possible) in the "Create a new Disk" task as I'm trying to keep everything dynamic and not hardcoded. (The .yml file is dynamic and created through automation)**

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to complicate things with a loop index trying to synchronize two different lists. Just loop over `vm_info.results`. It contains everything you need including the original `item` (accessible in `item.item` in the subsequent loop). See [registering with a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop)
2. Use `subelements`. For more information see:

- [The loop documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements)
- [The `subelements` lookup documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html)
- [The `subelements` filter documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_filter.html)

The following playbook should do what you need although it is impossible for me to test it in anyway as you did not provide an example of the data in the `vm_info` registered variable-

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    server_list:
      - cpu_count: 6
        memory_size: 12288
        name: nodeA
        vcenter: vCenterA
        vdisks:
          - capacity: 107374182400
          - capacity: 214748364800
      - cpu_count: 2
        memory_size: 2048
        name: nodeB
        vcenter: vCenterB
        vdisks:
          - capacity: 123415414552
          - capacity: 436345634633

  tasks:
    - name: Gather current VM information
      vmware.vmware_rest.vcenter_vm_info:
        vcenter_username: "{{ SECRET.USER }}"
        vcenter_password: "{{ SECRET.PASS }}"
        vcenter_hostname: "{{ item.vcenter }}"
        names: "{{ item.name }}"
      loop: "{{ server_list }}"
      register: vm_info

    - name: Upgrade CPU
      vmware.vmware_rest.vcenter_vm_hardware_cpu:
        vcenter_username: "{{ SECRET.USER }}"
        vcenter_password: "{{ SECRET.PASS }}"
        vcenter_hostname: "{{ item.item.vcenter }}"
        vm: "{{ item.value.0.vm }}"
        count: "{{ item.item.cpu_count }}"
      # There is no need for a when clause here. The task will
      # report "changed" if it was updated and "ok" otherwise
      loop: "{{ vm_info.results }}"

    - name: Create a new Disk
      vmware.vmware_rest.vcenter_vm_hardware_disk:
       vcenter_username: "{{ SECRET.USER }}"
       vcenter_password: "{{ SECRET.PASS }}"
       vcenter_hostname: "{{ item.0.item.vcenter }}"
       vm: "{{ item.0.value.0.vm }}"
       new_vmdk:
         capacity: "{{ item.1.capacity }}"
         type: SCSI
      loop: "{{ vm_info.results | subelements('item.vdisks') }}"
```

Comment: That fixed the issue for the looping, thank you! The only issue I'm getting next is figuring out how to work with the item_index. I'm using this method in order to grab the value of the VM ID within vm_info since the module doesn't allow the use of the hostname of the VM.

Comment: Updated the answer I can't test that new version since I don't have an example of your data. For your next question, please make sure you provide a full [mre] thanks.

Comment: I was able to workaround it as I grabbed the VM ID using the ansible vmware inventory plugin! It removed a task that I didn't need anymore from the playbook so it creates less calls to the API now. Thank you for all your help!